# readNullable is not working in scala with play2

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

i am validating a json coming from UI 
i have an optional field in case class that i am using for validation and parsing json
here it is

```
case class SignUpValidation(firstNname : String, 
                                          var lastName: String, 
                                          var email: String,
                                          var secondryEmail : Option[String] )
object SignUpValidation {

  implicit val artworkReads: Reads[SignUpValidation] = (
(JsPath \ "firstname").read(minLength[String](1)) and
(JsPath \ "lastname").read(minLength[String](1)) and
(JsPath \ "email").read(email) and
(JsPath \ "secondryemail").readNullable(email)
)(SignUpValidation.apply _)

}
```

i am validating incoming request like this

```
jsonRequest.validate[SignUpValidation].fold(
      valid = {
 // validation successful
 }, 
 invalid = {
 // validation failed
  } )
```

when i do not enter anything in secondryEmail filed and submit the data , validation should be successful but instead invalid block runs
please guide me what is my mistake

Comment: Show us error, what does `json.validate[SignUpValidation].toString` return? Maybe your `email` field is not valid email?

Comment: Is `secondaryemail` being submitted as an empty string?

Comment: @Infinity my error response contains this in invalid block {"obj.secondryemail":[{"msg":"error.email","args":[]}]}}

Comment: @m-z yes it is submitted as empty string

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to be however you are translating form to JSON. From above it looks like it might be an empty array? I am able to validate with non existent secondary email or empty secondary email as below:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._

case class SignUpValidation(firstNname : String,
                        var lastName: String,
                        var email: String,
                        var secondryEmail : Option[String] )

object SignUpValidation {
 implicit val artworkReads: Reads[SignUpValidation] = (
  (JsPath \ "firstname").read(minLength[String](1)) and
  (JsPath \ "lastname").read(minLength[String](1)) and
  (JsPath \ "email").read(email) and
  (JsPath \ "secondryemail").readNullable(email)
)(SignUpValidation.apply _)
}


val js =
"""{
   |"firstname":"bob",
   |"lastname":"frank",
   |"email":"bob@gmail.com",
   |"secondaryemail":""
   |}
 """.stripMargin


val result = Json.parse(js).validate[SignUpValidation]

println(result)


val js2 =
 """{
    |"firstname":"bob",
    |"lastname":"frank",
    |"email":"bob@gmail.com"
    |}
  """.stripMargin


val result2 = Json.parse(js2).validate[SignUpValidation]

println(result2)
```

console output

```
js: String =
 "{
   "firstname":"bob",
   "lastname":"frank",
   "email":"bob@gmail.com",
   "secondaryemail":""
 }"
result: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[SignUpValidation] =      JsSuccess(SignUpValidation(bob,frank,bob@gmail.com,None),)
js2: String =
 "{
  "firstname":"bob",
  "lastname":"frank",
   "email":"bob@gmail.com"
 }"

result2: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[SignUpValidation] =     JsSuccess(SignUpValidation(bob,frank,bob@gmail.com,None),)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all be carefull with your tiping, it can cause spelling errors to your code. I wrtie this an this works:

First your case class with a Companion Object

```
package models

import play.api.libs.json.{JsPath, Reads}
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._

/**
 * Created by anquegi on 06/05/15.
 */
case class SignUpValidation(firstNname : String,
                            var lastName: String,
                            var email: String,
                            var secondryEmail : Option[String] ){
}

object SignUpValidation {

  implicit val SignUpValidationReads: Reads[SignUpValidation] = (
    (JsPath \ "firstname").read(minLength[String](1)) and
      (JsPath \ "lastname").read(minLength[String](1)) and
      (JsPath \ "email").read(email) and
      (JsPath \ "secondryemail").readNullable(email)
    )(SignUpValidation.apply _)

}
```

then the POST method in you controller

```
package controllers


import models.SignUpValidation
import play.api.libs.json.{JsError, Json}
import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {

    Ok("Play Framework Scala Stack OverFlow")

  }

  def testSignUpValidation = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>

    val signup = request.body.validate[SignUpValidation]

    signup.fold(
      errors => {
        BadRequest(Json.obj("status" ->"KO", "message" -> JsError.toFlatJson(errors)))
      },

      signupObj => {

        Ok(Json.obj("status" ->"OK", "message" -> ("signup "+signupObj.toString) ))
      }
    )
  }
```

with the URL in routes:

```
POST   /testsignupvalidation controllers.Application.testSignUpValidation
```

I Used curl an the JSON from the user Barry to test it:

```
[anquegi@localhost ~]$ curl --include --request POST --header "Content-type: application/json"  --data '{"firstname":"bob","lastname":"frank","email":"bob@gmail.com"}' http://localhost:9000/testsignupvalidation
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 81

{"status":"OK","message":"signup SignUpValidation(bob,frank,bob@gmail.com,None)"}


[anquegi@localhost ~]$ curl --include --request POST --header "Content-type: application/json"  --data '{    "firstname":"bob",    "lastname":"frank",    "email":"bob@gmail.com",    "secondryemail":"bob2@gmail.com"  }' http://localhost:9000/testsignupvalidation
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 97

{"status":"OK","message":"signup SignUpValidation(bob,frank,bob@gmail.com,Some(bob2@gmail.com))"}
```

be carefull wit secondryemail and secondaryemail
You should not submit secondryemail when it is an empty string in other case it will fail by mail validator like this:

```
[anquegi@localhost ~]$ curl --include --request POST --header "Content-type: application/json"  --data '{    "firstname":"bob",    "lastname":"frank",    "email":"bob@gmail.com",    "secondryemail":""  }' http://localhost:9000/testsignupvalidation
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 81

{"status":"KO","message":{"obj.secondryemail":[{"msg":"error.email","args":[]}]}
```